# AT&T U-Verse and Macbook Pro Wireless connection drops

Tags: wireless-networking, macbook-pro, airport

I got AT&T U-Verse set up. Everything's fine except that my Macbook Pro and my daughter's Macbook Pro lose wireless connection every 15 minutes or so. When that happens, I can't ping to the router (192.168.1.254). I have to turn AirPort off and turn it on, then it starts to work again. But connection is lost again later.

So far, my Windows 7 laptop seems ok.

After some research, I changed the following things but no luck.

1. I disabled 'Wi-Fi Protected Setup' in the router.
2. I changed the wireless channel to 9 from auto.
3. I set DNS to outer server not the router
4. I turned off IPv6 on my Macbook Pro.

Has anybody experienced this problem?

Comment: Having identical issue. Wifi works for 10-15 mins then connection is lost. Rebooting airport gives you another 10-15 mins. Called tech support and they did some temporary fix about 3 weeks ago but now back to the same behavior, calling again now.

Comment: My iPad2 also has a problem with this wireless network. Same symptom. I guess all Apple products have an issue with U-verse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have identical issue. Wifi works for 10-15 mins then connection is lost. Rebooting airport gives you another 10-15 mins. Called tech support and they did some temporary fix about 3 weeks ago but now back to the same behavior.

Just called again:

- I went through two techs,  first one was friendly but not that knowledgeable.  second (Justin) seemed to know more.   says it is a mac-specific issue that others have and is not router specific.
- One *possibility* is to change the channel your wireless router broadcasts on, by going to

http://192.168.1.254/xslt?PAGE=C_2_1

he couldn't guarantee this would help at all but he said give it a shot.

- Also he changed security from WPA to WEP-open

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I already changed the channel and it didn't help. I'll try WEP-open.

Comment: I changed it to WEP-Open and it's been ok so far. Yeah~ Thank you very much.

Comment: May wish to put an inexpensive router in the DMZ of your 2Wire device and disable wireless on the 2Wire device itself to avoid relying on WEP-Open as your encryption method.

Comment: How do I change from wpa to wep?

Comment: Having this exact same problem - I switched both the channel and the security from WPA to WEP-open, hopefully that works. Advice for anyone else who tries this: connect to Ethernet first! If you change your wifi settings while you're on wifi, the connection drops when the new settings are applied and then can't pick back up because it doesn't know what they are ;-)